# Is "location" a reserved word in react? If so, what does it do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const location = 'abc';
const template = <p>Location: {location}</p>;
ReactDOM.render(template, document.getElementById('app'));
```

The above code keeps redirecting my page to '/abc'.

Babel compiles the above code to:

```
'use strict';

var location = 'abc';
var template = React.createElement(
        'p',
        null,
        location
);

var appRoot = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render(template, appRoot);
```

I suspect that the "location" variable name is reserved for React, but am not sure why this keeps happening.
Can anybody explain what the problem is? Am I not supposed to use 'location' as a variable name when using React?

Comment: location is a reserved word in very browser..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not specific to React, but just a collision with the global [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) object, that provides access to the current URL.

> The `Window.location` read-only property returns a `Location` object with information about the current location of the document.
>
> Though Window.location is a read-only Location object, you can also assign a DOMString to it. This means that you can work with location as if it were a string in most cases: `location = 'http://www.example.com'` is a synonym of `location.href = 'http://www.example.com'`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, I guess somewhere in the transpiled JavaScript, ReactDOM is creating a `Location` object with the specified value 'abc'? Which redirects the page to /abc ...?

Comment: The assignment `var location = 'abc';` is what causes this. The global `location` object already exists, so the `var` keyword has not effect here (assuming this whole block is in the global scope.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! As you have said, `var location = 'abc';` was the problem. Erasing the JSX expression still produces the same redirection.

Answer (score 1):

From what I assume, your code above is working. You are defining **const location** which will be a variable.

Refresh will only occur if you do **location = 'abc'** or **document.location = 'abc';**

Correct me if I am wrong.